# What would you call this style structure?

Tags: svg

I'm trying to modify a SVG file that was originally generated by a graphics editor. I don't recognise what it has done in the  section and I haven't been able to find the right guidance in documentation.

Specifically, it defines three classes cls-1, -2 & -3 and they appear to build on each other by the .cls-x references after the brackets.

Is this cascading, inheritance, shadow-tree? None of the guidance I've found shows such a structure.

Thanks in advance,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="Layer_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1{stroke-width:2.8px;}.cls-1,
      .cls-2,
      .cls-3{fill:none;stroke:#FFF;}.cls-1,
      .cls-3{stroke-miterlimit:10;}.cls-2{stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;}.cls-2,
      .cls-3{stroke-width:2.5px;}
    </style>
  </defs>

  <g id="Layer_1-2">

    <!-- 180mm rectangle with corner radius 20 -->
    <rect   class="cls-1" x="10" y="10" width="180" height="180" rx="20" ry="20"/>
```

I've tried defining new classes in a similar structure but can't make any sense of the results

Answer (score 0):

Let's reformat to make things easier to read...

```
<style>
  .cls-1 {stroke-width:2.8px;}
  .cls-1, .cls-2, .cls-3 {fill:none;stroke:#FFF;}
  .cls-1, .cls-3 {stroke-miterlimit:10;}
  .cls-2 {stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;}
  .cls-2, .cls-3 {stroke-width:2.5px;}
</style>
```

- The . means what follows is a class name so the first rule sets stroke-width: 2.8px for class name cls-1
- [commas separate selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors) so the second rule sets fill: none and stroke: #FFF for cls-1, cls-2 and cls-3. I.e. the same set of styles is associated with all three classes without having to repeat the style rule three times.
- the other rules add more properties to one or more of those classes.

Comment: Very well explained, thanks Robert!